# Suppose a tree graph T with $n\ge 4$ ,and 3 edges $e_1,e_2,e_3$ from its complement tree graph T-.Show that $G = T + e_1 + e_2 +e_3$ is a planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, trees, planar-graphs

can't seem to find the proof for this problem.
I know that a Tree graph has the property: $n = m - 1$ where $n$ is the number vertices and $m$ is the number of edges.
Also not sure if the restriction for planar graphs $m \le 3n - 6$ is sufficient to prove that a graph will be planar, as there are graphs that are not planar that satisfy the requirement $m \le 3n - 6$.
I believe graph $G$ will basically be graph $T$ with all its vertices connected but I can't see how that helps me prove it's a planar graph.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

A tree with $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges; when we add three more, we get $n+2$. You should begin by proving the following stronger claim: in any $k$-vertex subgraph of $T + e_1 + e_2 + e_3$, there are at most $k+2$ edges.

*(Hint: what is the maximum number of edges in a $k$-vertex subgraph of $T$?)*

Meanwhile, a graph is planar unless it contains a subdivision of either $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$. You can show that:

- A $k$-vertex graph which is a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ contains $k+3$ edges.
- A $k$-vertex graph which is a subdivision of $K_5$ contains $k+5$ edges.

*(Hint: what happens to the vertex and edge count when we subdivide an edge?)*

Putting these facts together, we conclude that $T + e_1 + e_2 + e_3$ cannot contain a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$, so it must be planar.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! :)